# Android update custom XML imageView by id

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, simpleadapter

I am very new to Android. I am working with a list view which uses a custom list_v.xml to house x2 textviews. I have also included a imageView which I would like to update through the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:maxHeight="40sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:maxHeight="35sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

I have updated the textviews via Json using this simple adapter concept but I would like to set the imageView for each row the same. I could hardcode the drawable to the xml above but I would like to reuse this view and update the image for other views if that makes sense.

Heres my activity class where I update the textViews but how do I programatically update the imageView to use the same image for all rows.

The imageView src will not come from my Json request it will be a drawable in the package.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();


        try {

            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String cat = "Category: " + c.getString(TAG_Cat);
                String title = c.getString(TAG_Title);

                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_Cat, cat);
                map.put(TAG_Title, title);

                oslist.add(map);
                listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(TopTipsActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_Cat,TAG_Title},
                        new int[] {R.id.title,R.id.body});

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(TopTipsActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("Title"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have tried to use

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
 image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tip_selected);
```

I am guessing I somehow need to reference list_v not listView.findViewById. I am probably missing the point completely.

Comment: yes you need to access each row/element of the list and then find ImageView from it. So basically you should use a custom adapter class extending BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's so simple, just edit your `HashMap` to

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_Cat, cat);
map.put(TAG_Title, title);
// the following line will add the default image to your map
map.put("Image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

and edit the `SimpleAdapter` to

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(TopTipsActivity.this, oslist,
                    R.layout.list_v,
                    new String[] { TAG_Cat, TAG_Title, "Image"},
                    new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.body, R.id.icon});
```

Comment: Gosh it really was simple again I am really new to Android! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I could hardcode the drawable to the xml above but I would like to reuse this view and update the image for other views

It not make sense. The adapter will create Views as he needed and you don't save any memory by this approach AFAIK.

Anyway, if you want to achieve your goal you need to extend BaseAdapter class and override it getView() method.

class CustomArray extends SimpleAdapter {

```
    public CustomArray(Context context,ArrayList list1, int resource,
                       String[] list2, int[] list3) {
        super(context, list1, resource, list2, list3);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,     ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(R.drawable.tip_selected);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And create it:

```
 private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown() {
    CustomArray adapter = new CustomArray(TopTipsActivity.this, oslist,
            R.layout.list_v,
            new String[] { TAG_Cat,TAG_Title},
            new int[] {R.id.title,R.id.body});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```